# Checkbox: make ng-click run when checked by ng-checked/ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in keys">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master">
            {{ x.key }}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="lang in languages">
            {{ getTranslation(x,lang.id) }}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(x,lang.id)" ng-model="master">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

my problem is that if i check the first checkbox, my other checkboxes will be checked without running the ng-click. How can i make the ng-click run when the checkboxes gets checked via the first one? I tried with ng-change as well.

Comment: The reason is you are using same `ng-model` that is `master` for two inputs. Try using two separate keys.

Comment: But I need the second checkbox to toggle (and call the ng-click function) when i toggle the first checkbox. I added some more code, maybe it shows my situation a bit more

Comment: What do you want the user to see when she clicks the first check box? What do you want to happen to the other checkboxes?

Comment: When one clicks the first checkbox, i want the other checkboxes that had been made for that "x in keys" to made checked. This is what happens right now, but when the other checkboxes gets checked this way the ng-click is not run for them, which is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

the "ng-change" directive should be ok. 
try this Example:

```
    <script>
        angular.module('changeExample', [])
            .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.counter = 0;
                $scope.change = function() {
                    $scope.counter++;
                };
            }]);
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1" />
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" id="ng-change-example2" />
        <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
        <tt>debug = {{confirmed}}</tt><br/>
        <tt>counter = {{counter}}</tt><br/>
    </div>
```

you can find this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: Not sure that is what i am looking for. I added some more code in my example to try to show my situation better

Comment: you should use <label> to pair with <input>

Comment: you cannot use `ng-model="master"` to update the checkbox input status, cause it's in the ng-repeat template. use a flag in the data obj can make it, in your case,

Comment: <td>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.flag"> {{ x.key }}
</td>
<td ng-repeat="lang in languages">
 {{ getTranslation(x,lang.id) }}
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="x.flag =!x.flag" ng-model="x.flag">
</td>